# Separate classes for different user types in Django

Tags: django

I'm writing application which implements three different user types:

- `Admin user` (Django Admin)
- `Mobile user` (django rest framework)
- `External user` (django rest framework)

The problem is that `External user` and `Mobile user` are much different from `Admin user`, for example they use different type of username field for authentication (and different authentication backends too), so I can't do this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "AdminUser"

class AdminUser(DjangoAbstractUser):
    username = models.EmailField()

class MobileUser(User)
    custom_field = ...

class ExternalUser(User)
    custom_field = ...
```

The question is, if I use three separate classes (the code is below) and three different authentication backends, will there be any consequences of that? For example `request.user` will store three types of classes: `ExternalUser`, `MobileUser` and `AdminUser`.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "AdminUser"

class AdminUser(DjangoAbstractUser):
    username = models.EmailField()

class MobileUser(DjangoAbstractUser)
    username = models.IntegerField()
    custom_field = ...

class ExternalUser(DjangoAbstractUser)
    username = models.CharField()
    custom_field = ...
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common anti pattern. Don't do this. You will have to spend thrice the effort to make your project work. Instead what you need is a UserProfile model (which you will have to create anyway for most projects)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ADMIN = 'A'
    MOBILE = 'M'
    EXTERNAL = 'E'

    USER_CHOICES = ( (ADMIN,'Admin), ....)

    user = models.OnetoOneField(User)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices = USER_CHOICES )
```

This gives you the same information but there's only one model and iet's simpler to implement and maintain

Comment: But users do not have a common part. You suggest that dealing with nested relation and nullable fields normalized over three completely different structures is a better idea? You are right, my solution breaks some Django pattern, but your solution breaks DB and Objective patterns. The question is which is better? :-)

Comment: Mine definitely does not break DB patterns. The proof is in the fact that you are extending the `User` models.  All users do have common parts used for authentication.

Comment: "All users do have common parts used for authentication." - they don't :-) `AdminUser` uses email/password fields. `MobileUser` uses two-factor authentication using phone nubmer as a login and external service. `ExternalUser` uses three unique fields as a login.

Comment: Then why on earth are you deriving from `User`? anyway, the situation you describe can still be modelled quite easily with my suggestion. Use it with Django allauth

Comment: "Then why on earth are you deriving from User" - Not from `User`, but from `DjangoAbstractUser`.

Comment: Which appears to be a third party model adding further complexity to an already clouded system